# If I change the name of a css .class and <div> the page stops working

Tags: html, css

I admit that I'm a novice, but this is crazy.  What am I doing wrong?

I had simplified my html page to a single css class and single div. It creates what I want... a single blue bar across the screen.  But if I change the name of the div and class, the page no longer draws my div.

All I am doing is changing the name of both from class1 to class2.

Why? Help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.column-left{  width: 33%; background-color: red;}
.column-right{  width: 33%; background-color: blue;}
.column-center{   width: 33%; background-color: green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <div class="column-left">Column left</div>
   <div class="column-right”>Column center</div>
   <div class="column-center”>Column right</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This shows a single red bar with the text "column left". Underneath is the text "column right". Then nothing else.

Comment: Please include the code in your post instead of a comment, and format it as code (by indenting it with four spaces, or selecting all of it and pressing control/command+k).

Comment: What actually you are changing? There is no **class1** which you have stated that you are changing. I will suggest you to post that code as well after making changes which is causing issue for you.

Answer (score 2):

Observe this line

```
<div class="column-right”>Column center</div>
                      // ^ here
```

`”` and `"` is different

Use `"` and not `”`

```css
.column-left{  width: 33%; background-color: red;}
.column-right{  width: 33%; background-color: blue;}
.column-center{   width: 33%; background-color: green;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="column-left">Column left</div>
   <div class="column-right">Column center</div>
   <div class="column-center">Column right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I fixed the quotations " in my sample above and it now works.  This was a product of using TextEdit on the Mac. 

But my original file with all the code is still not working.  I have a div for a grey bar at the top of the page.  I have some more code that works fine.  Then I try to put the same div class at the bottom of the page, but it will not style at all.  

eg. <div class="dividerbar">
<some other divs>
<div class="dividerbar">

The last line does not work.  Very frustrating, because the <some other divs> has multiple divs using the same class, and it works. 

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to understand and debug, if you add rest of the code to the question as well.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that, but it's very long.  I have div and class called "divider_bar".  It displays a nice grey horizontal bar.  So I copy and paste both, and add a "2" to the end, so I have "divider_bar2".   But the page will not read the second div.  This is soooo frustratingly simple.  I am copying and pasting directly, then simply adding a new character.

Comment: May be because you have css style defined for `divider_bar` and not for `divider_bar2`. Also if the code if very long you can share it via https://jsfiddle.net link

Comment: Thanks VaTz88.  I do have a css style defined for both.  I continue to debug.  I can get two different divs in a row.  Ie. a gray bar and then a green bar.  Great!  But I cannot delete the green bar and move it to the bottom of the page.  ie. After the gray bar I have div container.  It has 8 divs within it. (8 tiles).  There is a closing div for the container. If I try to place any of the divider bars after this, nothing happens.  Can't I just copy code that works and paste it elsewhere.  (sorry, will try to learn jsfiddle). THanks.

Comment: Problem is with your CSS. Not a CSS pro but changed `height` to `line-height` in ccs property for `.divider_bar3` and now it works. Copy code from here to your code file and open in your browser https://jsfiddle.net/VaTz88/9sxp8tj7/1/

Comment: Thanks VaTz88.  I see that you changed height: to line-height: and now it works.  This is great.  But I used the height property for divider_bar2{} and it worked.  Why would one extra character in a class name requires a different property to work?  I may post that as a separate question.  Because how will I ever know which one is which?  Anyways, thanks so much for taking on this problem!   It will replace [link](http://waterfallsofontario.com)

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the quotes here:

```
<div class="column-right”>Column center</div>
<div class="column-center”>Column right</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the quotations " in my sample above and it now works. This was a product of using TextEdit on the Mac. But my original file with all the code is still not working. I have a div for a grey bar at the top of the page. I have some more code that works fine. Then I try to put the same div class at the bottom of the page, but it will not style at all. eg. <div class="dividerbar"> <some other divs> <div class="dividerbar"> The last line does not work. Very frustrating, because the <some other divs> has multiple divs using the same class, and it works. Thanks.

Comment: <div class="divider_bar">1</div>
<div class="divider_bar2">2</div>

Comment: So that last <div> had `id=` instead of `class=`.